# LAST_CONVERT column in DBA_LOCK

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

What is the significance of LAST_CONVERT column in [DBA_LOCK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_4111.htm#REFRN23116)? There doesn't appear to be anything relevant in the documentation and I could not find anything elsewhere. What is the idea behind this column?

Also, is a good way to find out for how long a lock is being held?

Comment: What `LAST_CONVERT` column in `v$lock`? The [9i](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch396.htm#1116909), [10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1147.htm#REFRN30121) and [11gr2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_2027.htm#REFRN30121) documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: It's actually the dba_lock table (and not V$LOCK) thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has different levels of locks - a detailed explanation is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm

Within our transaction we can go from a lower level to a higher level which is what LAST_CONVERT tracks - the number of seconds since we went from a lower level lock to an upper level.